# Lambda Calculus operators precedence

Tags: lambda, lambda-calculus, operator-precedence

I have problems understanding lambda calculus operators precedence.

For example the following code:

```
lambda x.x z lambda y.x y
```

is going to be:

```
lambda x. (x (z lambda y. x y))
```

or

```
lambda x. ((x z) (lambda y. x y))
```

?

Even more complicated examples:

```
(lambda x.x z) lambda y.w lambda w.w x y z
```

where in the above example the parentheses go ?

I know that lambda application is left associative but does lambda values
have higher precedence over applications?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Application has higher precedence than abstraction. Together with the fact that application is left-associative and abstraction is right-associative, this leads to the following:

```
lambda x.x z lambda y.x y
```

is

```
lambda x. ( (x z) (lambda y. (x y)) )
```

and

```
(lambda x.x z) lambda y.w lambda w.w x y z
```

is

```
(lambda x. (x z)) (lambda y. (w (lambda w. (((w x) y) z))))
```

Comment: Thank you :) It was simple after all!